# javascript to add second class to element on click event

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a second class to my element on click

**Before**

```
<div class="foo1">
    <a class="class1" >Text</a>
</div>
```

**After**

```
<div class="foo1">
    <a class="class1 class2" >Text</a>
</div>
```

here are my javascript codes; both of them work:

**either this one (thanks to @Shomz)**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('class1 ');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    element.className += ' class2';
}
```

**or this one (thanks to @t-j-crowder)**

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".class1 "), function(element) {
    element.className += " class2";
});
```

**Question**

The site allows the users to click on **class1** and change it to **class1 class2** . However, by running these codes, the class1 *only* temporarily changes to *class1 class2*, I mean the clicking event is not implemented, it has only visually changed. When the site is reloaded, it is back to the previous state. How to apply a fix to change *permanently* the class by clicking on it?
How to achieve the class changing through a click event and to record this permanently? How can these js codes record this click and change it permanently?

Comment: You'd need to store the change somewhere. A database, cookies, localstorage, etc.

Comment: There's no such thing as making changes _permanently_ when it comes to front end, if you're applying them dynamically. You need to _save_ them somehow, somewhere, just like @j08691 pointed out.

Comment: Do you want the class's to change for that one user or for all users of the page?

Comment: @nepeo: for all users.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so based upon your comment you need to communicate the change to a server, then when the page loads it needs to request the data back from the server to reflect any stored changes. Theres a number of ways to do this depending on your programming capability, preference in language and compatibility requirements.

The most popular method would likely be a data file that is written dynamically by a php script. When the page is loaded it would generate your content based upon the contents of the datafile on the server(not to be confused with your HTML page). When the user modifies and element your page would call the php script using the AJAX POST method in javascript, then the php script would read the existing datafile, modify it accordingly and save it to the server.

For starters you will need a web server with PHP; if your testing locally MAMP is a good choice for Mac and I believe they now do a windows version as well.

Your would have 3 files( presuming all of your css and js is written in your HTML file):

- index.htm
- data.js
- update.php

Assuming a linear list of div elements, each with a switchable class and child content.

**index.htm**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='datafile.js'></script>
    <script>
    window.addEventListener('load',onload,false); //register the on load handler

    function onload(){
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var newelement;
        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
            //for each element in the data file
            newelement = document.createElement('div');
            //create a div element
            newelement.innerHTML = elements[i].content;
            //place the content within the div
            newelement.className = elements[i].class;
            //set our classes
            body.appendChild(newelement);
            //add the div to the body
            newelement.addEventListener('click',onclick,false);
            //add a click listener to the element
        }
    }

    function onclick(){ //on click function
        var elementIndex = elements.indexOf(this); //this will be the element in the callback context
        //modify class
        postchange(elementIndex,classList);
    }

    function postchange(element,class){
        // new post method
        // data = {'element':element,'class':class};
        // post data to update.php
    }
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**data.js**

```
var elements = [
    {
        "content":'Hello I am div 1',
        "class":'classA'
    },
    {
        "content":'Hi, I have been known as div 2... but you can call me Tim',
        "class":'classA classB'
    }
]
```

I've left the PHP out, it's not my main language so I don't feel happy improvising any code for you without looking it up and testing it first. That and it shouldn't be too hard for you to find information on POST methods on Stack Overflow.

Similarly I left the POST method in the JS out because the standard JS method is a little overcomplicated. Look up the jQuery POST method which is much more simple, again examples should be easy to find.